# Hangman with Arrays in Python 3.2

Tags: python

```
import random

GameWords = ['COMPUTER', 'PYTHON', 'RUBY', 'DELPHI', 'LAPTOP', 'IDEALS', 'PERL']
#Program will pick a word to use
word = random.randint(0,6)
ChosenWord = GameWords[word]

ChosenWord = list(ChosenWord)   

#This will generate a playfield
playField = "_" * len(ChosenWord)
playField = list(playField) 

#Array for bad guesses
BadGuess = "_" * len(ChosenWord) * 2
BadGuess = list(BadGuess)
print(" Bad Guesses", BadGuess)
print("\n Hidden Word ", playField, end = "")

#Get the number of letters in the word
WordLength = len(ChosenWord)

#Give two times the number of letters in a word for guessing.

NumChances = WordLength * 2
print("")
print("\n Number of Chances", NumChances)
print("\n This is number of letters in word", WordLength, "\n")

#Need a loop for the guess

flag = True
GoodCounter = 0
b = 0

while flag == True:

    #Input a player's guess into two diffrent arrays
    #Array for bad guess one for good guess
    PlayerGuess = input("\n Guess a letter: ")
    PlayerGuess = PlayerGuess.upper()

    #Player cannot enter more than one letter
    if len(PlayerGuess) != 1:
        print("Please enter a single letter.")

    #If the player do not enter a letter
    elif PlayerGuess not in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
        print("Please enter a LETTER.")

    #If the player guess wrong
    # b is used for indexing    
    elif PlayerGuess not in ChosenWord:        
        for b in range(0):                    
            if ChosenWord[b] != PlayerGuess:
                BadGuess[b] = PlayerGuess
                b = b + 1
        print("this is b", b)        
        print("You have guessed wrong")
        print("Letters you have missed", BadGuess)

        NumChances = NumChances - 1
        print("You have", NumChances, "left!")

        if NumChances == 0:
            flag = False
            print("You have lost!")
        else:
            flag = True

    #If the player guess correctly
    # i is used for indexing

    elif PlayerGuess in ChosenWord:
        for i in range(WordLength):
            if ChosenWord[i] == PlayerGuess:
                playField[i] = PlayerGuess
        print("\n Letters you have HIT! ", playField, end = "")
        print("You have guessed correctly")       
        GoodCounter = GoodCounter + 1


        if GoodCounter >= WordLength:
            flag = False
            print("You have won!")
        else:
            flag = True
```

Now I have a new problem my BadGuess array will not display the letters on the play field. I tried to use the same code I used for the playField array but it did not work.

What do I need to do to get the bad guesses to be stored in the BadGuess array and display on the play field?

Comment: "declare variables" - there's your first problem. Python doesn't have variable declarations. What you're doing when you write `BadGuess = [str]` or `GoodGuess = str` is assigning the type object `str` to `GoodGuess` and a 1-element list whose only element is `str` to `BadGuess`.

Comment: @user2357112 I took out the "declare variables" but now python keeps saying my variables are not defined so how do I define variables in python if python dose not declare them?

Comment: If you want `BadGuess` to be a list, assign a list to it: `BadGuess = []`. However, there's no need to have an assignment to, say, `ChosenWord` at the top of your program just to tell Python you're eventually going to use that name to store a string. Assigning `ChosenWord = GameWords[word]` will inform Python that you want to use the variable `ChosenWord`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're asking, but if you want all the bad guesses stored in the array, you have to increment the bad variable.

If you want to replace the blanks, there are many ways to do so, but I'd create a loop that tests to see if a letter is the same as in the word at a given index, and then replace it in the array if it does.

Something like:

```
for i in range(WordLength):
    if ChosenWord[i] == playerGuess:
        playField[i] = playerGuess
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you this has helped me with getting the letters to display the right way.